# Multiple connections issue trying to connect PCs across network

Tags: networking, windows

Trying to connect across network to PC runnign windows vista from laptop running Win 8.1.

Am getting 'Multiple connections to a server or shared resource by the same user, using more than one user name, are not allowed'.

There is no domain on this network.

Anyone know what I can do?

Comment: It seems that this question is not about professional system administration, and thus [off-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) at serverfault. Your question might be better suited over at [superuser.com](http://superuser.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a `net use`, delete all connections that are not relevant, then try again